# Why is index.php not used as my index file when using RewriteEngine in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

On my website, I have the following .htaccess file to have cleaner urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This is working great when users type in hostname.com/filename, however it cancels the automatic redirect when users browse to hostname.com/map/, as the RewriteEngine automatically adds .php after the map, which gives the following result:

```
https://hostname.com/map/.php
```

Is there a way of using index.php as my index file being used when an user browse to a map instead of a file, while still having the same effect on users browsing to a file? So the expected outcome is based on 3 options:

- The user is browsing to https://hostname.com/file: In which case the RewriteEngine should automatically redirect the user to https://hostname.com/file.php without changing the visible url;
- The user is browsing to https://hostname.com/map/: In which case the RewriteEngine should automatically redirect the user to https://hostname.com/map/index.php without changing the visible url;

Comment: I hope this is clear enough, it sounds a bit messy when I read the question again. I will try to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if the configuration automatically use `index.php` you just have to add
after `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Should I change the -f in my example to -d, in your example? Or add the condition with -d below the given example?

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems this fixed the issue! I'm using both conditions at the moment, as you suggested, however it seems to work with just changing the condition in my example to your version  (with -d), is there any reason why this seems to work as well, or why I shouldn't use it?

Comment: With `-f` you test if one file exist with the same name and don't add `.php` in this case. With `-d` you test for directory. it's a good idea to test both. You can read that for more info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond